# ErrorDocument 404 / error.php redirect but error.php page css and js not work

Tags: .htaccess

I add a error.php page in my web root for all error. Error page redirect by root htaccess rule which redirect well but page css and javascript not work (not loading).

But If I test as: www.myweb.com/error.php its display well format.

My server Apache Version 2.2.27 and PHP Version 5.4.28

my htaccess redirect rule

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
```

my full htaccess

```
# compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
# remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent

suPHP_ConfigPath /home/myweb/public_html/php.ini

# expire 1 week to images, css and javascript files
<FilesMatch ".(swf|ico|css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>

#Remove php#
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

#Remove Userprofile#
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ userprofile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]

#RewriteEngine on# 
rewritecond %{http_host} ^www.myweb.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://myweb.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

#RewriteEngine on#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^111\.111\.11\.111
RewriteRule (.*) http://myweb.com/$1 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php

# secure htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</Files>

#Disable server signature#
 ServerSignature Off

# Fix Rewrite
Options -Multiviews
```

Comment: What do you mean they do not work? Are they not loading? and where do they not work in your site or in the error.php file?

Comment: They are not loading sir. but if I test as: myweb.com/error.php its display well.

Comment: Do you have any other rules in your htaccess file?

Comment: Update with all htaccess rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your css/js is not loading it might be because you're using relative paths.

You can use the `base tag` in the head section of your html for the path to your css and js files. Then you can use relative paths. e.g

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/assets/">
```

or you can put a `/` in front of your paths to your files.

Otherwise inspect element in the broswer and check the console to see why it's not loading. It give a reason.