# CSS and JS won't show with a 404 redirect

Tags: javascript, html, css, apache, .htaccess

I made a custom error message with .htaccess. I put CSS and JS in there and in seperate folders and it works fine.
But now when I try to call them through the 404 Error message, it just shows the HTML text and no CSS or JS.
This is what my .htaccess file looks like:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error/index.html
```

I also tried

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error/
```

But that didn't work either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ErrorDocument 404 / error.php redirect but error.php page css and js not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28612698/errordocument-404-error-php-redirect-but-error-php-page-css-and-js-not-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This happen because you are using relative links in your files. and you are using different different directories for your web docs.**

Try this

> Put your custom 404 page to root/ directory.

or

> use base tag in your every html/php page and set root as default
>   base. more about base tag [read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

or

> manually sets relative links of your 404 page. 
>    like `<link
>   rel="../your-css-dir/your-file.css">`

also do it same for your js file.